# How to render Window custom Title using XAML?

Tags: wpf

I have a Windows Forms Application that shows application Name on most application Forms as shown below. For application name 'VScodePrint 2015' I used a bitmap. To support high resolution screens I had to make a number of copies of this image to support different DPI settings.

[image: About Window]

I have just started redesigning my application using WPF to avoid having to set different images based on the DPI setting without using images.

I have created a WPF window but not sure how to render the application name like the Windows Forms version above.

[image]

Can some please show me how to render the application as per Windows Form version using XAML?

Answer (score 0):

```
System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name);
```

Set a label or whatever control's content equal to that, and you will get the name as you are wanting.

Comment: That works as long as I want just the name but I want text '2015' aligned with the RHS of Name as shown

Comment: Ok, so make a label above the label that displays the Application name.. and then in the XAML for the top Label, put HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" , which will align it to the right side of the label.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to create a usercontrol that renders Window title for my windows. I am novice using WPF so may this not be the best XAML but here it is:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WindowTitle"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
         mc:Ignorable="d" Height="109.986" Width="404.929">
```

```
  <RowDefinition Height="80"/>

  <RowDefinition/>

</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Border BorderBrush="DarkGray" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="10,10,0,0 " Background="#FF61238B" Margin="0,0,0,1">
  <StackPanel Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
    <StackPanel Height="Auto" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
      <Label x:Name="lblYear" Content="2015" FontSize="12" BorderBrush="White" Foreground="White" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Padding="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontFamily="Global User Interface" Margin="0,5,0,0"/>
      <Label x:Name="lblProductName" Content="VScodePrint" FontSize="48" BorderBrush="White" Foreground="White" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Padding="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Global User Interface" Margin="0,-5,0,0"/>
    </StackPanel>

  </StackPanel>
</Border>
<Label x:Name="lblVersion" Content="Version 14.0.20 Rev 1510" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Height="37" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"  Margin="0,0,0.429,0" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold">
  <Label.Background>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFDBCBE3"/>
  </Label.Background>
</Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the above Window Title usercontrol in action:

[image]